# How can i get android notification on youtube video upload?

Tags: android, video, youtube, notifications, youtube-api

I'm coding a youtuber's android application.
It's almost done, but I would like to show a notification when a video has been uploaded (just like official youtube app do).
I don't wan't to frequently wake up the app  and check if a new video is available...
I found that ([push notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications)), but don't understand how to implement it into my app...

Can someone explain me how to achieve that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the youtube push notifications in coordination with GCM to achieve this:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Use the GCM server to in coordination with the youtube API to get the new video information, and then publish the notification about the new video to the application.

Comment: A tutorial on how this might work can be found here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-server-to-send-push-notifications-with-gcm-to-android-devices-using-python

Comment: I'm able to send push notification from https://www.internetfaqs.net/sc/gcm/index.php?success to my app, but do not understand how to join GCM with https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe ...

Comment: You wouldn't use pubsubhubbub to do the notifications. You'd follow the guide on the link I gave to set up a server to push to gcm. Then, on that server, you'd write a small script that would query the youtube api for video updates, and if you found them, you'd send a push notification using gcm to all your users.